# Recording from Bluetooth headset using AudioRecord

Tags: android

I am working on app for audio recording using bluetooth headset.
Its Working for some android device but not for all.I have checked for versions,its not version issue.

Let me please explain the issue clearly, 1. I connect my app with a bluetooth headset device 2. I record an audio file through bluetooth mic. 3. The app has a functionality to replay the recorded file which when played.. is not heard on the bluetooth speaker. 4. If I disconnect the bluetooth and reconnect it right thn.. the bluetooth speaker starts working. 5. Is there some kind of session issue here that only Mic is working in the specific time frame? I also tried with different Bluetooth's and different phones.. Still the issue persist.

Below is my code :

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {          
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {`enter code here`
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, -1);             

            if (AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED == state) {
                Toast.makeText(RecordingActivity.this, "Blutooth Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startRecording();//my Recording function
                unregisterReceiver(this);
            }              
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED));  

    am.startBluetoothSco();
```

Comment: Can you be clearer on what you need help with? Is there any error log that you can share? Also do read our [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: I need help that above is my code is not working for all android devices and log is not showing me any error so please tell me where i am going wrong.

Comment: Let me please explain the issue clearly,

1. I connect my app with a bluetooth headset device
2. I record an audio file through bluetooth mic.
3. The app has a functionality to replay the recorded file which when played.. is not heard on the bluetooth speaker.
4. If I disconnect the bluetooth and reconnect it right thn.. the bluetooth speaker starts working. 
5. Is there some kind of session issue here that only Mic is working in the specific time frame? I also tried with different Bluetooth's and different phones.. Still the issue persist.

Comment: are you able to add this information to your question? let me know if you are not able to edit your question, I can add this information to your question.